# Passing in "any" class type into a java method

Tags: java, class, methods

Okay say I have a class:

```
public class ExampleClass() {
    public void exampleClassMethod(ArrayList<CustomClass> abcdefg> arrList) {
        ....
    }
    public void exampleClassMethod2(ArgumentToTakeInAnyCustomClass custClassArg) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to pass in any array list of any objects into that method in that class.

Let's say my custom classes to pass in would be CustomClass1, CustomClass2, CustomClass3.

How would I set up that method to accept any ArrayList that I pass in?  Also, lets say I just wanted to pass in one of those classes themselves, as in the second example method, how would I do that?

Thanks.

```
public void testerMethodInitiater() {
    CustomClass1 abc = new CustomClass1();
    tester((Object) abc);
}
public static void tester(Object abc) {
    //do stuff
    System.out.println(abc);
    if(abc instanceof CustomClass1) {
        System.out.println("This is a CustomClass1");
    }
    (I need to tell the program to create a new CustomClass1 here if it's a CustomClass1) tester;// = new Object<Universalvars.getClassInUse()>;

}
```

Code above prints out that the object is an instance of CustomClass1, but I'm not sure how to make a new CustomClass1 at this time unless I did a conditional statement naming all possibilities that could take place which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: for the second method you can use Interface as Wrapper

Comment: Why don't you pass `Object` ?

Comment: How would I go about that one?  Thanks.

Comment: @alfasin I think it can be more general. Like passing List so it is superset which include arrayList or...

Comment: I tried the object thing with no luck

Comment: What I think you are looking for for the second bit is [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Answer (score 1):

Any `ArrayList`:

```
public void example( ArrayList<?> arr ) { ...
```

Any type of `CustomClass`:

```
public void example( ArrayList< ? extends CustomClass> arr ) { ...
```

Edit:  For the second half of your question, you can create a new object of any type with reflection:

```
public void tester( Object obj ) {
  Object obj2 = obj.getClass().newInstance();
}
```

This requires that the class of `Object` has a zero-argument constructor.  I don't know why you'd want to do this however.  You might want to implement `clone()` instead, or you might want to think a little more about your real goal at the end of all this is.  Usually adding a polymorphic method to `CustomClass` solves these "what class do I have" type questions.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer though with the second one, It wouldn't be an arraylist, just a class being passed in.  How would that one work?

Comment: Oh, sorry missed that one.  Any custom class would just be `public void example( CustomeClass c ) {...`.

Comment: Let's also say I did the any array list one, how could I check to see what the array list consists of?

Comment: I understand if I knew the class type being passed in but lets say I wanted to be able to pass in three different types to the method.  Like (CustomClass1 argName), (CustomClass2 argName), (CustomClass3 argName).  Is there a way to set that up, or would I have to remake a method for each type?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure how to check the type of a parameterized type, I'll try to find it.  2.  To pass any type of CustomClass in a List, use the second example I gave in my answer.

Comment: Sorry to be so convoluted in my explanations, I find it hard to explain what I'm attempting to do at times.  With that in mind I have posted a sample to further illustrate what I'm attempting with the second part of my question.  The first part I really appreciate the answer to as well, as that does solve part one, part two is kinda nuts though.

Comment: Well, that seems to make the instance, though I can't write code to call methods from the class type that it is.  How can I get around this?

Comment: unless I have to use invoke, I think I may have been over thinking this or it may be unable to happen the way I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<Object>` to accept any List object in the method.

```
public void exampleClassMethod2(List<Object> custClassArg) {
    ....
}
```

use List instead of ArrayList as it give more flexibility.

Also you can use `List<? extends CustomClass>` if all the other customClasses extends from a base type.

Comment: The other classes do not extend from a base, they're all custom objects.

Comment: In that case you can use only `<Object>` List but typecasting it back to the Original List can be overhead. You can pass another argument which specifies the Type the `List<Object>` sent, so that you can typecast it back & call the class methods. Although I don't think this approach is recommended.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to handle the second part of my issue at hand?  I Posted some new code at the bottom of the question to help illustrate the issue. Nothing I"m trying seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part

1)`tester(Object s)` method will accept all Types of Object because any Object in Java internally inherits from java.lang.Object. So `tester((Object) abc);` not required at all.

2)Typecast abc to CustomClass1 using `CustomClass1 custom = (CustomClass1)abc`. I hope it works.

3)You can use `instanceOf` operator but I guess this is lot of overhead for the developer & makes the code unreadable. Use it only if required.